# Calculating Driving Times from Cities to each Raster Cell in State using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.4

I am doing a project for a depart of the Utah state in ArcMap 10.4.1.

The project is create a model that will value each raster cell for the state of Utah with driving times from each of the Top 2 Populated cities in each county. I have the county layer, but am having a really hard time trying to get the Network Analyst work.

Any ideas where to start?

I have tried to do the service area in the Network Analyst, and load the Facilities as the cities layer, but it keeps saying the "cities" aren't found in the Network Analyst layer. Additionally, I am not sure how to have it run driving times from each city to each raster cell. Most of the Network Analyst work has one or a few desired destinations. After I have all the cells valued for each driving time from each city, I will just take the max value.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in the drive times (not in the routes itself) and if you have a lot of facilities (here, your raster cell centroids), you should run an [OD cost matrix analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/types-of-network-analyses.htm#GUID-B878EABE-B042-48B5-AAAB-C2777E89F91A), not a service area analysis.

Rasters are not accepted as input in a network analysis so convert your raster to points with [Raster to Point](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-point.htm) and use the points as origins, and use your cities (I suppose it's a point layer) as destinations - or vice-versa.